# Does the Vigor skill improve Fast Healing?

Tags: skills, legend

The Vigor skill is one of the skills in Legend that has additional benefits just for being trained in it. At five or more ranks, Vigor improves a character's ability to be healed, adding five hit points "whenever they would be healed."

**Does Vigor's passive bonus improve Fast Healing?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

pg 152, in the vigor skill scaling bonuses section:
"5 ranks: Whenever an effect other than [Fast healing] would heal you any amount of hit points, it heals you that many hit points plus five instead."

It explicitly disallows [Fast healing] from the bonus